# How to achieve the following using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate-functions

I used switch statement to assign some text based on different value ; here it returns correct output.
Now from the above output ,again I need to filter out few documents using regular expression.
Some thing like "`where status likes 'open%'`"

```
db.accountMailLog.aggregate([
        {$match:{'$and': [{recipientId: "3003590"}, {recipientType: "2"}
        ]}},
        {$project :
            {
            '_id'          : 0,
            'logCreated'   : '$eventOccurredTime',
            'subject'      : 1,
            'resourceType' : 'email',
            'campaignName' : 1,
            'emailSendDay' : 1,
            'logDate'      : '$eventOccurredTime',
            'sentMethod'   : 'campaign-email',
            'visitorKey'   : '',
            'mediaHash'    : '',
            "status"       : {'$switch' :
                                {'branches' :
                                    [
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','1']},'then' : "delivered"},
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','2']},'then' : "opened"},
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','3']},'then' : "clicked"},
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','4']},'then' : "bounced"},
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','5']},'then' : "unsubscribed"},
                                    {'case' : {'$eq' : ['$status','6']},'then' : "complained"}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
        }},
```

]);

Thanks !!!

Comment: What is the **specific problem** you're having? And what **specific question** can we help you with? See [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post to clearly explain a problem and ask an actual, specific question.

Comment: Asking for "SQL Conversions" or essentially "Gimmie teh codez" is far too broad a question. Instead show sample documents from the collections as implemented with MongoDB, an expected result obtainable from those supplied documents and what you have attempted so far in order to solve the problem. We can help you with things you don't understand when you make an effort, but straight out writing the code requests are highly off topic

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regexp. Something like:

```
"status": open/
```